# Force Trailing Slash in .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is the below .htaccess code correct? It is used for SEO purposes. I found it in google but I want to be sure it is okay to use. It is placed in .htaccess file and used to force a slash on non-slash URLs. Also, specifically, is the /$1/$2/ part correct?

```
#Force Trailing Slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Will I need to also include a RewriteRule for the non-www url (see below) ?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Also, is it true that you only need to have the below ONCE at the very top of .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Also, how do you TEST if this code is indeed working? I put the code in my .htaccess file but my homepage does not display a trailing slash.

**Edit: Follow-up Question:**

Figure A

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/
```

Does "Figure A" Rewrite Rule only force a trailing slash for

```
http://www.domain.com/post-one
```

Will "Figure A" RewriteRule also force a trailing slash for

```
http://www.domain.com/category/post-one
```

If not, how do you add a grouping so that you can do the /$1/$2/ thing?
Would you suggest doing the /$1/$2/ thing (for SEO purposes)? Is there any harm to doing this?

Comment: see https://helponnet.com/2021/05/07/add-traling-slash-to-urls-using-rewriterule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> specifically, is the /$1/$2/ part correct?

No, youre going to get redirected to have 2 trailing slashes because `$2` doesn't backreference anything. `$1` backreferences the `(.*)` but you don't have a second grouping. You just need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

> Will I need to also include a RewriteRule for the non-www url (see below) ?

No, the 2nd parameter for the `RewriteRule` directive is the *target*, so unless you want to redirect people to `domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com` you don't need to add anything.

> Also, is it true that you only need to have the below ONCE at the very top of .htaccess?

Yes

TO test, just add your htaccess file and go to a URL without a trailing slash. The browser should get redirected and you'll see in the location bar the same URL but *with* a trailing slash. If that's not what you see, something else is wrong.

Comment: Jon thanks for your clear answers. Two questions. In addition to this .htaccess code, I added a trailing slash in MySQL database siteurl and home url. ---- But [my homepage](http://www.leko.pw) still displays WITHOUT a trailing slash. However everything else such as posts and categories displays WITH trailing slash. ---- What could be wrong? Is the homepage SUPPOSED to display WITHOUT a trailing slash? ---- Also, can you check out my "follow-up question" in my post above under "Edit"?

Comment: @leko if you mean `http://domain.com` as "home page", then htaccess can't do anything about that. The request that the rewrite module sees is `/` in both cases. As for the `(.*)` question, that matches everything, including `/blah` and `/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/blah`. It matches everything.

Comment: Jon Regarding "htaccess can't do anything about" homepage URL non-slash --- Are you saying this htaccess code will result in end slash ONLY for subpages such as www.domain.com/post/ but NO end slash for homepage www.domain.com ? Can you explain the reason ?

Comment: @leko A request for `http://domain.com` and `http://domain.com/` look exactly the same to apache, so there's no way to redirect one to the other